# AWS SNS Credentials update error message PlatformPrincipal not valid

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I've tried to Update Credentials of my production application in the AWS SNS service from Amazon, and I receive the following message:

> Invalid parameter: PlatformPrincipal not valid. (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: b9f5f6c6-...-b9ebbc13c4cd)

I think is not the most explanatory error message. 
So if someone could explain me what it means, or at least, where can I find the explanation to this error... options, something.

Is one of the worst error messages I've ever seen.

Som more information:

- Following the tutorial from here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html#verify-cert-private-key-apns
- Trying to give my production apps the ability to receive Push notifications

Any other required question, please ask I'll answer ASAP

Thanks

Comment: The error message seems to come from Amazon SNS, but the page you linked does not make any requests to SNS. You should share the detailed steps to reproduce the error message.

Comment: Thanks @YosukeMatsuda but I didn't have much to do, plus my main question was: Where can I find more information about this issue?
Anyhow, I've managed with a workaround, as i explain in the "solution"

Answer (score 1):

Well, for your information, this is a kind of generic response AWS gives to the user for a bunch of cases.

In my case, at the end I've created new credentials, I've created a python script that loads again all the devices to the new credentials, and done, the user doesn't know but his push notifications are going through another AWS credentials.

So if you are having this issue:

1. Review one more time the information you are introducing.
2. If you can, don't fight, is a wall, a thick one. A walkarond will be better than search for a way to break this wall.

Hope will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same error, but going to the SNS portal and uploading the new certificate there instead on in the MobileHub works, as a workaround.